# Animate sine function with red dot

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I'm trying to animate a sine function being drawn, but with a red dot on the newly drawn graph part. I've got the drawing to work, but the red dot keeps being plotted several times. This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

X = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 200)
Y = np.sin(X)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.set_xlim([0, 6*np.pi])
ax.set_ylim([-1.1, 1.1])

sinegraph, = ax.plot([], [])

def sine(i):
    sinegraph.set_data(X[:i],Y[:i])
    ax.plot(X[i], Y[i], 'o', color='red')

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, sine, frames=400, interval=50)
plt.show()
```

Basically I need the red dot to be erased and redrawn every frame.

Comment: Add `plt.cla()` and set axes limits in sine function? Do you want to show just one red circle while animating?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just as with updating the line, you can update your red dot, using the `set_data()` method of a previously defines line plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

X = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
Y = np.sin(X)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.set_xlim([0, 2*np.pi])
ax.set_ylim([-1.1, 1.1])

sinegraph, = ax.plot([], [])
dot, = ax.plot([], [], 'o', color='red')

def sine(i):
    sinegraph.set_data(X[:i],Y[:i])
    dot.set_data(X[i],Y[i])

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, sine, frames=len(X), interval=50)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here, I made the following changes to your code and I believe it now does what you intended it to do.

I added the  marker function that plots the pointer.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

X = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 200)
Y = np.sin(X)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.set_xlim([0, 6*np.pi])
ax.set_ylim([-1.1, 1.1])

sinegraph, = ax.plot([], [])

def marker(i):
    ax.plot(X[i-1],Y[i-1],'o',color='red',markersize=5)
    ax.plot(X[i],Y[i],'o',color='black',markersize=5)


def sine(i):
    sinegraph.set_data(X[:i],Y[:i])
    ax.plot(X[i], Y[i], 'o', color='red',markersize=5)
    if i>0:
        marker(i)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, sine, frames=400, interval=50)
plt.show()
```